# how to use modulus to wrap number between 1 and 7

Tags: bash

I have four elements I am changing the color of in bash. To change the color, I'm using

```
tput setaf [1-7]
```

I have the first element starting at 1, going to 7, and wrapping around just fine using nested loops, but i want each element to follow the one on its left.
So if I started with

RED GREY BLUE PINK

the colors would change to

GREEN RED GREY BLUE

then

YELLOW GREEN RED GREY

and so on until they got back the original orientation and repeated.

The only examples I've found for wrapping numbers around bounds wrap out of bounds numbers back to 0 using

```
x = (x+1) % N
```

where x is the current position(or color in my case) and N is the max value the numbers are allowed to reach, but I want to exclude 0(BLACK). I changed this to

```
(x-1) % N + 1
```

so each element follows the one on its left and adding one to avoid getting zero, but each element eventually runs into an off by one error because of that addition.

Here's my code so far:

```
K="0"
# iterate through all colors twice
while [ $K -lt 2 ]; do
for j in {1..7}; do
            # just positioning the elements/letters
            tput cup $(( $ROWS / 2 + $ROWS / 8 )) $(( $COLS / 2 ))
                tput setaf $j
                echo -n "T"
                tput setaf $(( ($j - 1) % 7 + 1))
                echo -n "E"
                tput setaf $(( ( $j - 2 ) % 7 ))
                echo -n "S"
                tput setaf $(( ($j - 3) % 7 ))
                echo -n "T"
                sleep 0.5
            done
            (( K++ ))
        done
        tput sgr0
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `x % 7` produces a number in the range 0..6, you need to add 1 to get a result 1..7.

```
tput setaf $(( ($j + 6) % 7 + 1))
echo -n "E"
tput setaf $(( ($j + 5) % 7 + 1))
echo -n "S"
tput setaf $(( ($j + 4) % 7 + 1))
echo -n "T"
```

Notice the uniformity of spacing; it helps reassure me there's at least a chance that the code is OK.  I also changed the subtractions into additions; you get negative results when you take the modulus of a negative number, which wouldn't help at all.  Adding 6 modulo 7 is equivalent to subtracting 1 modulo 7.

Comment: why not `$(( (j + 6) % 7 + 1))`?

Comment: Because I don't like that shorthand.  I like to see my variable references prefixed with `$` signs.  You may do as you wish.